# laravel mail function not render html tags

Tags: php, laravel, email

8 
and in my controlller i have this code

```
    $users = User::where('user_type','=',3)->get();
    return Mail::send(['text'=>'emails.sallery'],['$users' => $users],function($message){
        $message->to('pulldozr@gmail.com','awad')->subject('test email');
        $message->from('support@softya.com','awad alsharif');

    });
```

and this is my blade code

```
<h1>asdfadsfasdf</h1>
```

now in gmail the mail will come not as h1 will come like this

```
<h1>asdfadsfasdf</h1>
```

without rendering the html tags 
any help here thanks

Comment: Replace `['text'=>'emails.sallery']` with `'emails.sallery'`. See here for how the send function works: https://github.com/illuminate/mail/blob/master/Mailer.php (line 286 for parseView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code instead:

```
$users = User::where('user_type','=',3)->get();

Mail::send('emails.sallery', ['users' => $users] , function($message) {
   $message->to('pulldozr@gmail.com','awad')->subject('test email');
   $message->from('support@softya.com','awad alsharif');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please can you put it into html template not like what you have sent like this maybe:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>Mail</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>asdfadsfasdf</h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```